# Parse : Multiple queries with an array returning only when finished

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

trying CloudCode out for the first time and loving it.

I am writing an iOS app that passes phone numbers to CloudCode to see if a phone number already has the app.

The problem is its firing the success block before the queries finish. I am guessing I need to know how many queries there are and work out if on the last one? I also seen this .then function?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("processNumbers", function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var phoneNumbers = request.params.phoneNumbers;

    phoneNumbers.forEach(function(entry) {

        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        //query.equalTo("username", entry);

        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                console.log("has app");

            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("not found");

             }
        }); 

        console.log(entry);

    });

    response.success(phoneNumbers);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do use `promise` to perform task in series or parallel.

ref. [Promises in Parallel](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-parallel), [Promises in Series](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-series)

The following is a parallel version which use `Parse.Promise.when`. The promise `when` will be resolved when all of its input promises is resolved.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("processNumbers", function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var phoneNumbers = request.params.phoneNumbers;
    var promises = [];

    phoneNumbers.forEach(function(entry) {

        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        //query.equalTo("username", entry);

        promise.push(
            query.find().then(function(results) {
                console.log("has app");

            }, function() {
                console.log("not found");

            });
        ) 

        console.log(entry);

    });
    return Parse.Promise
        .when(promises)
        .then(function() {
            response.success(phoneNumbers);
        });

    response.success(phoneNumbers);
});
```

p.s. not tested yet, use at your own risk

Comment: is there anything else that you have to do when the inner promises (in the array) are themselves queries that return a result?  I can get it to work when I return .as(something), but not when adding a nested promise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832955/parse-cloud-code-sub-queries-with-parallel-promises.  Thanks!